# Load SAS datasets into Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, sas, apache-pig

we are looking for a way to load SAS datasets into hadoop as we are tyring a usecase in Pig and compare the performance. SASACCESS help achieving the functionality of treating Hadoop datasets in SAS. I coulnd't find anything in SASACCESS about this, is there a way this can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you looked at SAS Access to Hadoop reference doc @ http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/achadoop/65227/PDF/default/achadoop.pdf by the way which SAS version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

From SAS Access to Hadoop reference doc @ http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/achadoop/65227/PDF/default/achadoop.pdf page#9

```
libname sasflt 'SAS-library';
libname hdp_air hadoop user=louis pwd=louispwd server='hdpcluster' schema=statsdiv;
proc sql;
create table hdp_air.flights98 as 
select * from 
sasflt.flt98;
quit;
```